# SC7 and SC10 Lithology Classifications

Tags: geology, geography, sedimentology, soil

I am looking for the full names of the lithology classifications SC7 and SC10. According to the [FAO's guidelines for soil description](http://www.fao.org/3/a-a0541e.pdf) SC3 e.g. refers to *silt-, mud-, claystone*. What do SC7 and SC10 refer to?